# How to make .ico format icon in task bar appear transparent?

Tags: c#, winforms, icons, ico

I would like the background of the task bar icon that appears when my windows form application opens to be transparent. However, the icon has a white background when it appears in the task bar. I opened the .ico file and it has the checkered background that indicates transparency.

How do I make the background of the icon in the taskbar transparent?

This is the first time I have added an icon to a windows form application. I also tried with a .png file but what showed in the task bar was just the default .png icon.

Here is the code which declares object icon in the scope of the class:

```
Icon icon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon("galaxyicon.ico");
```

I use the code below in each Form_Load method to set the icon as the icon object in the task bar.

```
this.Icon = icon;
```

I expected a transparent icon in this case but got a white background instead.

Comment: An Icon file can be actually composed of multiple bitmaps objects. WinForms Forms use `16x16` or `24x24` icons. Up to `32x32` in Windows 10. The Icon file you're using, probably, does not fit the description. What happens if you set the Form's `Icon` property in the designer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define the "transparent" color of the icon, like:

```
//using System.Drawing;

#region MakeTransparentIcon

    ///<summary>
    /// Manipulates the background of an Icon
    ///</summary>
    ///<param name="icon">Icon source</param>
    ///<param name="disposeIcon">Icon dispose</param>
    ///<returns><see cref="Icon"/> or <see cref="T:null"/></returns>
    public static Icon MakeTransparentIcon(Icon icon, bool disposeIcon = true)
    {
        if (icon != null)
        {
            using (Bitmap bm = icon.ToBitmap())
            {
                bm.MakeTransparent(Color.Transparent); // define the background as transparent
                                                       // you need to align the color to your needs
                if (disposeIcon)
                {
                    icon.Dispose();
                }
                return Icon.FromHandle(bm.GetHicon());
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    #endregion
```

Comment: Doesn't apply to WinForms. Also, you're returning a BitmapImage, which can't be used as an Icon & GDI+ can't create icons from whatever source.

Comment: Thanks for the help, though in the task bar the icon shows the transparent grid behind it though it is not actually transparent. This is also the case for the icon shown in the top left hand corner of the form. Any idea why?

Comment: @tallen638 if you extract or view the icon, does it have a white background? If so, just try to replace `Color.Transparent` with `Color.White`.

Answer (score 0):

You should load the icon file directly [using `new Icon(fileName)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.icon.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Drawing_Icon__ctor_System_String_).

Comment: Thanks, however I replaced the code for instantiating the icon with this and the background remained white when I did     this.Icon = icon;